# How to view all results in WordPress (search widgets)

Tags: php, wordpress, widget, wordpress-theming

I work on WordPress search box. I can only 10 results to show, While I check this how many result I get, to use the following code,

```
$allsearch = new WP_Query("s=$fish&showposts=0"); 
echo $allsearch ->found_posts.' results found.';?>
```

there is 50 posts but show only 10 post. If I used pagination post per page is 10 pagination not showing. But I change to post per page is 5 pagination show well, But the total post are show 10 only.
How to fix this?

Comment: This must show all results `$allsearch = new WP_Query(array( 's' => $fish, 'posts_per_page' => -1, 'cache_results' => false ));`

Comment: Where I used this? I used WP_widgets_search

Comment: I try following code , but this also not worked